# How to optimize this mongo query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple mongo query here which uses aggregate function. It is taking 1 min and 38 sec to load 10 rows in my php script. How can I optimize this query as it takes lesser time.

```
$data = $mongo->command(
                                array(
                                    'aggregate' =>"my_collection",
                                    'pipeline' => array(
                                        array('$match' => $filter_query),
                                        array('$group' => array('_id'=>'$email')),
                                        array('$skip'=>$offset),
                                        array('$limit'=>10)
                                    )
                                ),
                                array( 'timeout' => "-1")
                            );
```

This is my query and the filter_query is another array which is

```
Array ( [event] => spamreport [timestamp] => Array ( [$gt] => 1384236000 [$lt] => 1384840800 ) )
```

Also I have one more query to find the distinct values like this

```
$distinct_notifications = $my_collection->distinct('email',$filter_query);
```

It is taking forever to load the distinct values. My collection is little larger and has around 20700144 rows. It is increasing day by day. Also it will be helpful if someone can point out a good map/reduce tutorial as I am new to this.

Comment: how amny rows are you aggregating? Also how amny are you skipping? Also does the query use an index?

Comment: @Sammaye No it doesn't has an index. I think this is aggregating all the rows matching the time stamp query and it is also little larger. This whole thing was working before when the collection is not this much larger. I am taking from 0 rows at first.

Comment: If there is no index then you will always get a full table scan. I would first advise to optimise your indexes

Comment: how can I add indexes from RockMongo ? I have this interface only.

Comment: I do not use rockmongo, though I do use PHP but I do index building from the console and in there I would advise running: `db.my_collection.ensureIndex({event:1,timestamp:1})`

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks man...almost done..now it has much better performance. It is taking less than 10s for most of requests.

Comment: @Sammaye now again this is taking too much time. I even added one more index but it is not loading if I issue the command to select data for one month.